# vim syntax highlighting - flexible recognition of custom keywords/types (typedef)

Tags: vim, syntax, typedef, highlighting

In my C++ code, I use customized types a lot like

```
typedef double type_scalar
typedef std::complex<type_scalar> type_complex
etc.
```

where I follow the convention that i always put type_* in front of my type names.
I use (G)VIM editor and would like it to syntax-highlight my custom types just like the built-in ones (without explicitly listing them all in the syntax file).

I searched the web for possible solutions and tried putting everything from regex expressions like

```
syn keyword cppType \<type_.*/
```

and

```
syn keyword cppType type_[^\ ]*\
```

to

```
syn match typedefSuffix     '\a\+'
syn keyword cppType     type_ nextgroup=typedefSuffix
```

in my ~/.vim/syntax/cpp.vim file, but I wasn't able to get the desired result, i.e. to get every instance of the form type_whatever highlighted.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
syn keyword cppType \<type_.*/
```

That one looks promising, except for:

- `:syn keyword` does not take a regular expression, only literal keywords; you need `:syn match` (and enclose the regular expression in delimiters)
- The `.*/` will match everything up to the last `/` in the line; you rather need `\w\+` to restrict the match to the remainder of the identifier, and `\>` to enforce the end of the keyword. Ergo:

```
syn match cppType "\<type_\w\+\>"
```

Put that into `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim`, and you should be good to go.

Your problems could have been resolved via the excellent documentation. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: What is better: `\w` or `\k`?

Comment: @Vitor: `\w` better fits the allowed characters for a C/C++ type name, and isn't as variable as `\k`.